# YouTube embed video player size still too small

Tags: html, youtube, embed, dreamweaver

A really simple but irritating problem. I am trying to embed a YouTube video in a simple HTML page with Dreamweaver, defining the player window to be larger. But no matter what I do, the player window is too small!

Here is the code I am using:

it's within a table which should be large enough.

But it looks silly and puny on the livesite: http://bigmyth.com/myths/english/2_zulu_full.htm

Please help! Lots of people are complaining.

Thank you.

Fiona

Answer (score 1):

Youtube embed video came with iframe tag. Please add width and height to the iframe itself
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0dzB.png).

```
iframe{
width:500px;
}
```

Comment: <iframe width=“1120” height=“630” src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/GuUPl5Rr1eE"VQ=hd1080 frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Comment: Ha! I thought `width/height` within `iframe` was the `style` attribute. The applied CS in the answer works! ty!